# What is the difference between a "real" multidim array and a onedim array holding arrays in VBA?

Tags: arrays, vba, multidimensional-array

In the first sub i'm creating a one-dim array holding two one-dim arrays in each data field (and these two arrays are also having two data fields each). In the second sub I'm creating a two-dim array with two data fields per dimension. If you `Debug.Print` the arrays you get the same results (both are holding the values 1-4).
So, is there any difference at all (for example concerning used storage)? What is the better method or is this just "a matter of taste"?

```vb
Sub oneDimArray()

    Dim arrayLarge(0 To 1) As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    arrayLarge(0) = Array(1, 2)
    arrayLarge(1) = Array(3, 4)
    
    For i = LBound(arrayLarge) To UBound(arrayLarge)
        For j = LBound(arrayLarge(i)) To UBound(arrayLarge(i))
            Debug.Print arrayLarge(i)(j)
        Next j
    Next i
    
End Sub
    
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub multiDimArray()

    Dim arrayLarge(0 To 1, 0 To 1) As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    For i = LBound(arrayLarge, 1) To UBound(arrayLarge, 1)
        arrayLarge(i, 0) = Array(1, 2)(i)
        arrayLarge(i, 1) = Array(3, 4)(i)
    Next i
    
    For i = LBound(arrayLarge, 1) To UBound(arrayLarge, 1)
        For j = LBound(arrayLarge, 2) To UBound(arrayLarge, 2)
            Debug.Print arrayLarge(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The first is a jagged array. Probably matter of taste.

Comment: Seems you're correct: "(...) so jagged arrays should not be confused with multidimensional arrays, but the former is often used to emulate the latter." Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array

Comment: You haven't created an array of arrays.  You have created an array of variants.  Variants have the property that they can store any other type of variable, you just happen to have stored arrays in the variants.

Comment: @freeflow: You're sure? If I ```Debug.Print VarType(arrayLarge)``` I get 8204 as result. According to the list of return values for ```VarType()``` 8204 means array  8192 + variant 14. Wouldn't this mean I get arrays of type variant in both cases? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function

Comment: @freeflow: Hm, seems you're correct indeed: the Array function "Returns a Variant containing an array." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/array-function
The return value of ```VarType()``` is nevertheless a bit confusing for me...